# How to assign a void** array (return value of a function) to a variable?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

Needed: A function which returns two different values (int,str)

So foo calculates smth. and stores the addresses of the two values
in the return array.

Now I want to read the values back into variables of these types.

```
void** foo(){
    void** bar = malloc(2 * sizeof(void*));
    ...
    return bar;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    void** result = foo();
    int* val1 = (int*)result[0];
    char* val2 = (char*)result[1];
}
```

This snippet is not compiling.

### Excuse me:

the problem was not the code but that I declared it in a case branch
without any compution instructions.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    switch(xyz){
      case a:
        void** result = foo();
        int* val1 = (int*)result[0];
        char* val2 = (char*)result[1];
      break;
    }
}
```

Which seems not to make sense in a case.

Thanks though.

Comment: What errors does the compiler give you?

Comment: This compiles fine for me when I comment the `...`. So what code are you omitting? That part's probably the problem.

Comment: "I have to execuse me"??

Comment: @machine_1 german speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you come up with the need to use a `void**`, it is a strong indication of poor program design. Just forget about this idea. `void` pointers in general is something you should avoid.

What you actually want to do seems to be something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int i;
  char c;
} something_t;

something_t* foo (void)
{
  something_t* result = malloc (sizeof(*result));
  ...
  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  something_t* result = foo();
  int* val1 = &result->i;
  char* val2 = &result->c;
}
```

If the struct members need to be pointers, simply change the struct.

Comment: Well, you still the fastest gun in the west. I wrote the same/identical code ;)

Comment: @LPs There's still a merit in posting the answer if you had it written, even if it's identical. Means there's two people saying exactly the same thing, which gives the answer(s) more weight :)

Comment: perhaps a `free(result); return 0;` for completeness?

Comment: I'll accept that use of `void **` is highly questionable, but "`void` pointers in general is something you should avoid" seems overly broad.  Indeed, one cannot easily avoid all use of `void` pointers, and you yourself did not do so in your own code, as that's what `malloc()` returns.  Consider also the `%p` field descriptor for `printf`, comparison functions for use with `qsort()`, *etc*..

Comment: Also, although this answer provides useful information, it does not respond to the actual question.  It cannot do so, as the premise of the question as currently written is false -- the OP's code is valid, except for the ellipsis.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes the standard C library is very flawed and irrationally written, but we just have to suck it up, it won't get fixed. That doesn't mean you should run off to write your own code in a similar way. The `qsort` function is an exception: the use of void pointers is justified there.

Comment: And it does respond to problem that was to be solved with the code in the question. The OP used the wrong solution to solve the problem. It is then our responsibility to point this out and provide the correct solution, not to help him fix his wrong solution. [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You should use structure to do your job

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING_WIDTH 32

struct test
{
    int val1;
    char *val2;
};

struct test *foo(void)
{
    struct test *bar = malloc(sizeof(struct test));

    if (bar != NULL)
    {
        bar->val1 = 0;
        bar->val2 = calloc (STRING_WIDTH, 1);

        if (bar->val2 == NULL)
            return NULL;
    }

    return bar;
}


int main( void )
{
    struct test *result = foo();

    if (result != NULL)
    {
        // USE YOUR STRUCT
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Take note that `malloc`ated memory must be `free`d

Comment: Good recommendation, but it doesn't respond directly to the OP's "Why doesn't this compile?" question.